# PHP check if an input has anything in it.

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a basic text input on a contact form. If there is anything written in the text field, i want the contact to NOT send. There are a lot of questions on here similar but I cant figure out a way to bend the complicated explanations people have given to fit my simple task.

```
    <input type="text" id="check" name="check"/>
```

Comment: Is this a ploy for anti spam?

Comment: yes it is. I have the style="display:none" but i didnt want to confuse anyone by keeping that in.

Comment: spam bots can detect if an element is hidden (we've had trials of this method),  so this method won't work very well. see my answer. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (isset($_POST['check']) && strlen($_POST['check']) > 0) {
    // something was entered
}
```

Comment: why not just use !empty()?

Comment: Because `"0"` is *empty* as well. :)

Comment: Sidstar - and because you'll trigger an undefined index warning (probably behind the scenes) if you don't check isset() first.

Answer (score 0):

For anti spam:

```
<form method="post" action="contact">
  <input type="text" id="check" name="check">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#check").remove();
});
</script>
```

On server-side:

```
<?php $isSpam = isset($_POST['check']); ?>
```

**UPDATE**

To help settle some details here... You wouldn't want to immediately discard submissions based on `$isSpam`, instead, you'll want to flag it. The front end result should NOT be different from submission to submission (spam submissions should show the same "thank you" message as a legitimate submission).

Secondly, you should use `$isSpam` to flag an email or a DB row as *potential* spam. The likelihood that it is spam is high, probably around 98%. This method is non-obtrusive to users.

See: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment reply. Every spam bot I've seen does NOT parse JS, so this is a fairly reliable method and is not obtrusive  ;)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it relies on jQuery, which is too much for just this task and also will not allow real users with disabled JS.

Comment: The concept is that spam bots take snapshots/caches of html code (particularly just forms), or enters/submits forms, but do not evaluate any JS code. Obviously if the field exists, and the form gets posted, JS did not get evaluated and you can safely determine a high probability that the submission is spam. Honestly, there are not many people who browse without JS in this new age. This leads me to this point: You shouldn't necessarily consider `$isSpam` as a 100% certainty... instead, flag the submission... Using `mail()`? Append "[SPAM]" to the header, so you can review it later... etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!empty($_POST["check"])) {
 // dont send
}
```

Comment: Will throw errors. if `$_POST['check']` does not exist. You should develop with error_reporting on fully.

Comment: what if the form is beign sent via AJAX ? then I am sure check is always set